# ajax auto comlete problem

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

Q:

I want to make autocomplete facility like the one exists in yahoo mail ,
when i write a mail address then i post it by(;) 
i see a list of mails begin with specific character , when i tried the ajax auto complete i face a problem ,when i write a name and post it by(;)and  begin to write the second name , it concatenate the first one with  the expected instances of the second one in the auto complete list. i want the same action in yahoo mail how to do this.
(no concatenation in the auto complete list)?

Comment: I am preparing an example for you asp.net webforms so you can have a look at it.

Comment: I've attached some code for you. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a simple effective solution you should have a look at [jQuery UI automcomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple-remote)
It quite easy to implement and it allows you to format the result the way you want; changing, for example, the , in ;
You can find some code [here](http://cid-669adf1af64df389.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/AutocompleteASPNET.zip)

Comment: this is great , but i note that the list is static i mean:

Comment: var availableTags = [
   "ActionScript",
   "AppleScript",
   "Asp",
   "BASIC",
   "C",
   "C++",
   "Clojure",
   "COBOL",
   "ColdFusion",
   "Erlang",
   "Fortran",
   "Groovy",
   "Haskell",
   "Java",
   "JavaScript",
   "Lisp",
   "Perl",
   "PHP",
   "Python",
   "Ruby",
   "Scala",
   "Scheme"
  ];
is there a way, allow me to get the options from the database,example please if possible

Comment: if your list is static you can look at this http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple the other link I've attached previously refers to remote data.

Answer (score 1):

You could use what Yahoo mail uses: 
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/examples/autocomplete/ac_local.html
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/examples/autocomplete/ac_datasource.html

How to get the information from your database: 
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/datasource/